# Retrieving value from an object within a Map

Tags: java, object, dictionary

I am writing an interpreter program and I am stuck at the moment with this.
There is a Map for Integers and MJObjects:

```
private Map<Integer, MJObject> objectHeap;

objectHeap = new HashMap<Integer, MJObject>();
```

MJObject class looks like this:

```
MJObject(SymbolTable symTab, String className)
```

I create a new MJObject and store it inside a Map with a reference integer.

```
public Integer allocClassInstance(String className)
MJObject object = new MJObject(symTab, className);
objectHeap.put(nextFree, object);
```

Then from another method using just the reference of the MJObject, I need to retrieve the className inside the MJObject. How can I do that? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then from another method using just the reference of the MJObject, I need to retrieve the className inside the MJObject. How can I do that?

If you've already got the `MJObject` then the map is irrelevant. Assuming the `MJObject` makes the class name it was constructed with accessible somehow, you just want something like:

```
String className = mjObject.getClassName();
```

If you're *actually* trying to get the key in the map which is associated with that `MJObject`, you'd have to iterate through the map - or potentially create a *second* map with the reverse mapping (`MJObject` to `Integer`).

Comment: The main thing is that I don't know if I am allowed to create an additional method to get className from inside MJObject. Are there any other ways or I should just try that?

Comment: @Gedas: Well we can't really guess it what you're allowed to do for your assignment, I'm afraid. You *could* maintain a separate `MJObject` to `String` map, but it would seem an odd thing to do.